# "deer's numbers" or "deer's population" or "deer population"

Tags: noun-phrases

Why "deer's numbers" is not correct and I should say "deer numbers" without 's

I have the same question for the phrase "deer population", is it right to say "deer's population"?

Why should I not put the possessive 's in these expressions?

Answer (score 2):

"Deer population" is correct since you can't own a population. Hence why it isn't called "Human's population". A place however can "own" a certain population. Places can own populations but a human or animal cannot.

I am not sure about "deer's numbers" or "deer numbers" since I have never heard anyone say that in the way that you are implying it. I think it is best for you to say "number of deer" population-wise.

Answer (score 1):

The population does not belong to the deer; the deer *are* the population. “Deer population” is a single compound noun, with the noun-adjunct “deer” operating as an adjective.

This may seem a bit confusing because we speak of a city’s or country’s population, but as with the deer, we do not think of the humans *within* that city or country as possessing themselves.

Comment: With the word “numbers”? Could I say “deer’s numbers” or is it totally wrong?